# can't initialize a GLfloat, 'conflicting types' error

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, initialization

(iPhone) Pulling my hair out just trying to declare and set a stupid variable. Here's the code:

```
const GLfloat zNear = 0.01, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 60.0; 
GLfloat size;
size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS*fieldOfView / 2.0));
```

Gives me the error "Conflicting types for 'size'".

If I write it like this instead:

```
const GLfloat zNear = 0.01, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 60.0; 
GLfloat size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS*fieldOfView / 2.0));
```

I get the error, "Initializer element is not constant".

What's really weird is that this code worked fine when it was inside a method. I moved it out of the method, and now it fails. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you supposed to have the double )) at the end of your statement?

Comment: `size` is a common variable name, so there might be a `size` instance variable or something else within your current scope with that name (which I've seen to cause the "conflicting types" errors in the past).  Try renaming it `calculatedSize` or something else and see if that removes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing at *global-scope*, statements can be assigned to only constant literals.

```
// At global scope
int a = 10 ; // fine
int b = a ;  // Not allowed
b = a ;      // Not allowed
b = 100 ;    // fine

const int aa = 10 ;  // fine
const int bb ;
bb = aa ;   // Not allowed
```

---

The solution is `#define`. Try this -

```
#define zNear 0.01
#define zFar 1000.0
#define fieldOfView 60.0

GLfloat size;
size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS*fieldOfView / 2.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use something like

```
#define kPosun 44.0
```

before implementation statement.